# subscript out of bounds in subset function

Tags: r, subset

I have several lists of columns (a, b, c, d). I need to use these lists to select columns from a large correlation matrix (the matrix is 66 rows by 66 columns).

I tried to use subset to obtain these columns from the correlation matrix.

```
x1 <- subset(correlmatrix$r, select=a)
x2 <- subset(correlmatrix$r, select=b)
x3 <- subset(correlmatrix$r, select=c)
x4 <- subset(correlmatrix$r, select=d)
```

a, b, c, d are character vectors.

a is composed of "Inhib"  "Humans" "Incl"   "Job"    "OtherP"

b is composed of "Affect"  "Posemo"  "Posfeel" "Optim"   "Friends" "Family"  "Excl"    "Occup"  "School"  "Achieve" "Physcal" "Body"    "Groom"   "Fillers"

c is composed of "Pronoun" "You" "Article" "Preps"   "Affect"  "Social"  "Othref"  "Friends"  "Present" "Future"  "Excl"    "Fillers" "AllPunc" "Period"  "Apostro"

d is composed of "Inhib"  "Tentat" "TV" "Quote"

Each of lists corresponds to a column in the correlation matrix.

b and c yield the following error:

> Error in x[subset & !is.na(subset), vars, drop = drop] :    subscript
>   out of bounds

My guess based on the error message and length of a thru d is that I have exceeded some size constraint.  How do I fix this?

Comment: It isn't clear what your overarching structure is. can you provide something like: `dput(str(lapply(mydata.corsig, head)))`? (remove portions that aren't necessary if it's a big mess.)

Comment: I cleaned up the question a bit. There isn't much of a "flow" the issue.  Just the four lines of code.

Comment: That doesn't really help. Now I wonder if `correlmatrix` and `mydata.corsig` are matrices, lists of matrices, data frames, etc. Regardless ... `select=` is supposed to be an *"expression, indicating columns to select from a data frame"* (or matrix), but none of your descriptions there include columns named "a", "b", etc.